# PHP - Detect string if contains only HTML tags or text with HTML tags

Tags: php

I get stuck into this.
I am using WYSIWYG text editor and when I save the result into my database if the textarea is empty it stills inserts `<div><br></div>` content into my database.
So my question is how I can identify if the string contains only HTML tags and no words?
I've tried using `strpos` but with no result and I am sure that this is not the right function for doing such a check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it isn't the right function. You have to use a regex for that.

Here is a regex that checks if in one string, there's only html tags :

`^(<[^>]*>)+$`

You can use it with the `preg_match()` function of PHP like that. This function returns `true` or `false` depending on if the regex is matched (if there are only HTML tags).

`$is_only_html = preg_match("#^(<[^>]*>)+$#", $string_input_to_check);`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strip_tags`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to check if there are only tags:

```
if (trim(strip_tags($str)) === '') {
    //only tags - no text.
}
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/I8CPpT